# How to run all tests in a python file from a python script?

Tags: python, unit-testing, continuous-integration, nose

How do I run all tests (unittest.TestCase) from a python file in a script?

I've tried using nose but it always seems to run the test discovery.
All I want is to import a module, give some function a path and get the test results back, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the bottom of your test script put

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then just call your file as normal

```
$ python my_test_script.py
```

Optionally, if you want to use `nose` or `pytest`, you can just give it the name of the script you want to run, it will still do discovery, but only on that one file.

```
$ nosetests my_test_script.py

$ py.test my_test_script.py
```

If you're running nose from inside python, you can use [`nose.run()`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html#nose.core.run)

***my_script.py***

```
import nose
nose.run()
```

By default, it will use the arguments you pass to the script, so if you only want to run a single test_script

```
$ python my_script.py /path/to/test_script.py
```

Or, you can pass the arguments directly inside your script

```
nose.run(argv=[__file__, '/path/to/test_script'])
```

Comment: I'm already in a python script, I don't wanna run another shell or anything.

Comment: How can I do what u do with Nose but with plain unittest? at the moment I get `module 'unittest' has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: @MoteZart `nose` will discover plain unittest-style tests. My first example shows how to use `unittest` via `unittest.main()`, though it offers far fewer options than discovering/running tests with `nose`.